# jQuery - картинки по одному пути

Tags: php, jquery, изображения

Сегодня я столкнулся с проблемой. Я загружаю на свой сайт картинку, процесс сохранения работает исправно. Однако, он сохраняет разные картинки на один путь. В следствии чего я не могу сменить картинку после загрузки на сервер по средствам jQuery..

Есть какие-либо предложения по реализации?

Comment: Приведите код на php, видимо, проблема в нём

Comment: Нет. PHP работает исправно. Картинка загружается. Лично проверял каждую строку var_dump и console.log.

Comment: Проблема в том, что картинка сохраняется по одному пути(так и должно быть). В следствии чего без перезагрузки страницы она не обновляется.

Comment: Ну так удалите img тег и вставьте новый. Возможно даже переприсвоение атрибута src будет работать.

Comment: Всё из этого уже попробовал.

Comment: Добавляйте таймштамп к урлу картинки, чтобы браузер снова за картинкой ходил

Comment: Можно примерчик кода? (впервые слышу о таймштампе)

Comment: `src_картинки = "image.png?" + Math.random()`

Comment: Работает. Спасибо!